# Glassfish session-timeout ignored in Vaadin application

Tags: java, glassfish, vaadin, session-timeout

We're using Vaadin application, and while in use, Vaadin eventually shows errors "Session expired", but in Glassfish, which hosts this app, session timeout is set to 8 hours (much more than period of time between the last access and getting 'session expired'). After debugging the app, we dug out this thing: while loading page, Vaadin requests session using `request.getSession(true)`, for subsequent ajax requests it uses `request.getSession(false)`; and eventually `request.getSession(false)` returns `null`, so `session expired` message appears. It seems that web container ignores session-timeout setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default session timeout in Glassfish is 30 minutes. If this matches your experience, the timeout setting of 8 hours (28800 seconds) is somehow ignored completely.

You can specify the timeout in glassfish-web.xml:
glassfish-web-app > session-config > session-properties > timeoutSeconds

Or you can have a session-timeout element is specified in the web.xml file. This overrides the timeoutSeconds value.

Comment: Thanks for answer. We specified 4hrs session timeout in web.xml, now trying to repeat the error.

Comment: Didn't noticed any problems now, I'm marking question as answered. Thanks for your reply